I need to merge top 2 rows in dataframe
My dataframe is in below format.
input:
|col1 |col2 |col3|
|-----|-----|----|
|ab   | cd  | ef |
|gh   | ij  | kl |
|mn   | op  | qr |

I want to merge only top2 rows.
output:
|col1| col2|col3|
|----|-----|----|
|abgh|cdij |efkl|
|mn  |  op | qr |

I created dataframe using pandas. All my top 2 rows either have null values or string values.

What happens if you have more than 3 rows?

I think OP would like to merge only the two first rows, and keep the other rows.

Here's one approach:

Select top rows (df.iloc), convert None to empty string (df.fillna), and use df.agg with join.
Chain Series.to_frame and df.T to get it in the right shape to reattach via pd.concat:

out = (
    pd.concat([
        df.iloc[:2].fillna('').agg(''.join).to_frame().T, 
        df.iloc[2:]
    ], ignore_index=True)
)

Output
   col1  col2 col3
0  abgh  cdij   ef
1    mn    op   qr

Data used
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': {0: 'ab', 1: 'gh', 2: 'mn'}, 
         'col2': {0: 'cd', 1: 'ij', 2: 'op'}, 
         'col3': {0: 'ef', 1: None, 2: 'qr'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # adding a `None`

df

  col1 col2  col3
0   ab   cd    ef
1   gh   ij  None # added `None`
2   mn   op    qr


You can combine numpy.arange and groupby.agg:
If you want to aggregate every two rows, use:
import numpy as np

df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).agg(''.join)

If you only want to merge the first two and leave all the rest independent:
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))>1).agg(''.join)

or:
df.groupby(np.clip(np.arange(len(df)), 1, len(df))).agg(''.join)

Output:
   col1  col2  col3
1  abgh  cdij  efkl
2    mn    op    qr

